# get information about places with freebase api

Tags: java, json, api, freebase

I am working on freebase API. I have a JSON query where I am trying to get information about places that contain in a town from freebase.

I had a problem with the input geolocation when I used the latitude and longitude from wikipedia. When I put the geolocation that I take from `freebase.com` is working correct but not for all the towns. Is there a problem with my query?

Code:

```
query = o("name",name,"type","/location/location","geolocation",a(o("latitude",latitude,
             "longitude",longitude)),"contains", a(o("name",null,"id",null,"optional","optional","type","/location/location",
             "geolocation",a(o("latitude",null,"longitude",null,"optional","optional")),"limit",800,"count",null)));
```

Error: `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of hard to tell since you aren't using JSON syntax and you've provided no context as to where the NPE is occurring, but one definite problem is that "optional" takes a True/False value, not the string "optional".

I'd recommend debugging your query using the [Freebase query editor](http://www.freebase.com/queryeditor) and only munging to be Java compatible at the last minute when you've got it all debugged.

Comment: "optional": "optional" is a synonym for "optional": true, so that's not the problem. Everything else Tom says is correct though :-)

Comment: @Tom Thank you very much..i used Freebase query editor and i solved my problem. Can i ask you something else? Do you know how can i find the type of the category and the type of the description. For example the type for the geolocation is /location/location.

Comment: That sounds like a different question.  If you post it with the Freebase and/or MQL tags, I (or someone else who's quicker) will answer it.